# Android App Crashes When Trying to Rotate an Image Continuously

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

Created an ImageView in my app and wanted to rotate it continuously, but when I try to run the app on my phone it crashes immediately. Here is my code:

Java Activity File:

```
public class FrontPage extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);
    initialize();

    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation1.setDuration(2000);
    rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    iv.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
}

private void initialize() {

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.motorolaLogo);

}
```

XML File:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/motorolaLogo"
            android:src="@drawable/motologo"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `iv`. It's a `Null Pointer Exception`.

A null pointer exception is an attempt to use the null object. In your case you declare ImageView iv but never assign a value to it. Afterwards you have an attempt to use one of its methods, but since it's not properly initialized, it's the equivalent of writing `null.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);`

To avoid these kinds of mistakes you simply have to make sure your objects have proper values assigned before you attempt to use their methods...

****amended after discussion
You're inflating the wrong xml. Instead of

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);
```

you need to have

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_front_page);
```

otherwise, your `Activity` will never find the correct object.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Your answer is quite short.

Comment: @bjb568 I respectfully disagree. user3462023 asked why his app was crashing and I answered why.

Comment: What's a null pointer exception? How do I avoid it? Is there anything else that I should be aware of? Is there documentation of this?

Comment: @bjb568 a null pointer exception is an attempt to use the null object. In your case you declare ImageView iv but never assign a value to it. Afterwards you have an attempt to use one of its methods, but since it's not properly initialized, it's the equivalent of writing null.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);

Comment: To avoid these kinds of mistakes you simply have to make sure your objects have proper values assigned before you attempt to use their methods...

Comment: That response should be part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DigCamara. I realized that I tried to change some variable names when copying the code over but didn't change them all. My intent was to initialize the value of iv in the `initialize()` method by using the following code: `iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.motorolaLogo);` Is that sufficient as an initialization, or does the constructor for the ImageView class also have to be called?

Comment: I reckon that should be enough. Why did you change your question?

Comment: Then is there anything else wrong/incomplete about my code? Because the app still crashes when I try to run it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to post the logcat

Comment: Yeah sorry, here is the logcat. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at moto.fitness.FrontPage.onCreate(FrontPage.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)`

Comment: It says there's a null pointer exception so it must be a problem in declaring either the ImageView or the RotateAnimation right? Is my declaration of the RotateAnimation object incorrect?

Comment: Not really sure. What do you have on line 47?

Comment: `iv.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);`

Comment: A couple of questions then: your activity's xml file is named activity_front_page.xml? Did you change your code to use the iv variable? Because it seems that the line iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.motorolaLogo); isn't actually assigning the correct object.

Comment: The .xml file that contains the ImageView object is fragment_front_page.xml, and the java file that modifies it is FrontPage.java. Does something in the activity_front_page.xml file need to be changed so the line `iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.motorolaLogo);` assigns the correct object? I thought since the ID of the ImageView in fragment_front_page.xml is motorolaLogo, it would reference the correct object when assigning the ImageView object in the java code.

Comment: Look at the amended answer. You're asking Android to look for your ImageView in the wrong file.